# How to deal with post containing real ID documents?

Tags: discussion, revision-history, privacy

*I don't want to link to that specific question just to avoid unnecessary publicity. Could one of the moderators look at my flag history. The one currently pending is referring to that question.*

Someone posted a scan of what seems to be a real ID document. I pointed out that perhaps that wasn't the best thing to do. The user has since hidden details from the scan but the original scan is still available through the revisions history.

Rotating passwords posted by accident is easy but rotating ID cards or passports may be slightly more challenging. I understand that as soon as it's online we must assume it's already too late but perhaps we should get it out of the revisions history anyway?

Comment: A moderator flag is the way to go. They can get stuff removed from revisions :)

Comment: cross site : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or/132119#132119

Comment: @yivi It does answer the question however is it ok to create a post linking to that question? (As mentioned I'm not sure if driving traffic to that question is the best thing to do)

Comment: No need to create a post linking to the question. The answer in the dupe says it clearly: _"Flagging is the appropriate action here"_.

Comment: It's too late anyway:(